# About affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the definition of affine space over a field $K$, Shall $K$ be a closed field or not? and why? 
I am confused because some references mention that the field $K$ must be closed, but I didn't know what is the purpose!
thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by closed? Algebraically closed? To define affine space, you don't need to assume $K$ is algebraically closed, but for the later theorems (Nullstellensatz, Bezout's theorem, etc), you need to assume that so many introductory books do assume this right from the start. Affine spaces are just the sets  $\mathbb Q^n,\mathbb R^n,\mathbb C^n,\mathbb F_q^n$ (and in general $K^n$ for a field $K$) without their usual vector space structure.

Comment: @Ravi You miss out the "big" points in there depending on your definition of affine spaces. Either you are looking at something vectorspace like (with translation space and so on) or you are looking at something more algebraicly with prime ideals as points. In both cases you dont need (algebraicly) closed. Can you please specifiy in your question, what affine means for you and what closed means for you?

Comment: Yes, I mean algebraically closed field.

Comment: If $k$ is a field, then $\mathbb A^n(k) = k^n$ as a set. However, if $k$ is alg. closed, then $\mathbb A^n(k)$ can be endowed with the Zariski topology (see Hartshorne Chapter I.1). If $k\to \overline{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$, then $\mathbb A^n(k) $ naturally becomes a subset of $\mathbb A^n(\overline{k})$. Note that the subspace topology on $\mathbb A^n(k)$ is not as easy to describe as the Zariski topology on $\mathbb A^n(\overline{k})$.